# starttime changes on CalendarRule when I insert it into work hours in CRM

Tags: timezone, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

When I submit a CalendarRule to CRM's work hours, the StartTime changes just before it is submitted to the database. I submit the CalendarRule through the code below. The submitted StartTime differ by -2 hours. I suspect this has something to do with the fact that I live in +1 GMT timezone and our clocks are set to dayligt time savings.

```
var calendarFrequenceRule = new CalendarRule
{
    Duration = 24 * 60, //24 hours
     ExtentCode = 1,
    StartTime = start.Date,
    Pattern =
        new CalendarRulePattern
        {
            ByDay = new List<DayOfWeek> {start.DayOfWeek},
            Interval = 1,
            Frequency = CalendarRulePattern.FrequencyEnum.WEEKLY
        }.ToString(),
    Rank = 0,
    TimeZoneCode = userSettings.TimeZoneCode,
    InnerCalendarId = new EntityReference(Calendar.EntityLogicalName, innerCalendarId),
};
calendarRules.Clear();
calendarRules.Add(calendarFrequenceRule);
userCalendarEntity.CalendarRules = calendarRules;
OrganizationService.Update(userCalendarEntity);

var calendarTimeRule = new CalendarRule
{
    //Name = name,
    //Description = name,

    Duration = (int)(end - start).TotalMinutes,
    Effort = 1.0,
    IsSimple = true,
    Offset = (int)(start - start.Date).TotalMinutes,
    Rank = 0,
    TimeCode = (int)TimeCode.Available,
    SubCode = (int)SubCode.Schedulable,
    TimeZoneCode = -1,
    CalendarId = new EntityReference(Calendar.EntityLogicalName, innerCalendarId),
};
calendarRules.Add(calendarTimeRule);
newInnerCalendar.CalendarRules = new List<CalendarRule> {calendarTimeRule};
OrganizationService.Update(newInnerCalendar);
```

When I retrieve the time again through the code below the time is off by 4 hours. I've checked that all users have their time zone settings set to the same time zone - but to no avail. When I look at the database I can see that the time zone submitted through code is the same as the calendar rules I've insert through the GUI.

Code to retrieve the CalendarRule:

```
var user = OrganizationService.Retrieve<SystemUser>(userId);

var expandCalendarRequest = new ExpandCalendarRequest
{
    CalendarId = user.CalendarId.Id,
    Start = start,
    End = end,
};

var response = OrganizationService.Execute<ExpandCalendarResponse>(expandCalendarRequest);
return response.result;
```

Comment: What time is off by 4 hours?

Comment: Just noticed you never actual asked a question, just made a whole bunch of statements...

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you insert a DateTime into CRM using the SDK or the Odata endpoint, it assumes that it's UTC.  If you update a field via javascript, it will assume it's in the time of the current users.  I'm not sure what case you're currently working with, but always work with UTC unless you're editing fields in the actual form.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22787954/227436 for an overview of working with Time in CRM.

This answer has a function that maybe useful in your case as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367508/227436

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. As I see it, the service doesn't assume that I'm giving it an UTC-timestamp - rather it wants to convert it to UTC for me. As the interface saves the TimeZoneCode along with the timestamp (see first example above) I really don't see why it would convert it to UTC.

Comment: @Frederik Is your first code snippet Javascript or C#?

Comment: Hi Daryl. I'm sorry that I didn't specify that. It's C#

Comment: @Frederik Unless `start` is already UTC, `start.Date` is going to return a non-UTC DateTime Value and CRM will convert that to UTC in the database and will be returned as UTC in your C# code base.

Comment: Hi Daryl. I found that if I supplied a datetime with the DateTime.UTC-kind it wouldn't be changed. But it's kinda odd that it would change it to UTC since I also supply timezonecode along with the datetime. Then when I retrieve the timeslots of the workhours through ExpandCalendar-request it will assume that the datetime in the DB is local and convert it to UTC - Once again ... Seems like a bug to me.